# Correlation of correlations

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, paired-data

I have the following datasets:

```
df_a.head()
     biomarker0  biomarker1  biomarker2  biomarker3  biomarker4
0      0.605402   -1.211484   -1.079286    1.928360   -3.954883
1      0.251319   -0.113781    0.734295   -0.438365   -0.672190
2     -0.613029    1.976055   -0.315305    0.867435   -0.194201
3     -1.130581    2.312527   -0.296570    0.980829   -0.284964
4     -0.718135   -1.608488    0.949036   -0.003182   -0.551495

df_b.head()
       score0    score1    score2    score3    score4
0    1.479649 -0.779951 -0.537458 -0.185120  0.042280
1   -0.615173 -0.455070  0.227971 -0.283392  0.076041
2    1.958981  1.106898 -0.341664 -0.342833 -0.300475
3   -0.855617  1.551850 -0.346749  1.396121  2.433128
4    2.232390 -1.623430 -0.781096 -0.967153 -0.148262
```

`biomarker` and `score` are different variables!

To compute the similarity of `biomarker` values between **samples** and the `score` values between **samples**, I calculate two separate correlation coefficients:

```
biomarker_corr = df_a.T.corr()
score_corr = df_b.T.corr()

# biomarker_corr
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000  0.229148  0.136553  0.086046  0.147228
1  0.229148  1.000000 -0.325497 -0.308354  0.464533
2  0.136553 -0.325497  1.000000  0.992075 -0.561738
3  0.086046 -0.308354  0.992075  1.000000 -0.476849
4  0.147228  0.464533 -0.561738 -0.476849  1.000000

# score_corr
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000 -0.493064  0.601905 -0.504112  0.982617
1 -0.493064  1.000000 -0.845631  0.207953 -0.388481
2  0.601905 -0.845631  1.000000 -0.474574  0.593460
3 -0.504112  0.207953 -0.474574  1.000000 -0.582884
4  0.982617 -0.388481  0.593460 -0.582884  1.000000
```

Now, I would like to know if the samples whose `biomarker` correlations are high happen to have high `score` correlations, too.

Does it make sense to then do a *correlation of correlations* or is there a different strategy we should use here? Or is this something for meta-analysis? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not inspect a scatterplot?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks again as always. Are you suggesting to just plot, say, bio marker correlation on the x axis and the score correlation on the y axis? I have considered that as an initial step, but would it then be correct to do another correlation analysis on top? I wasn’t sure how kosher that is.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing you should do.  Whether it's "kosher" or not will depend partly on the data -- but the scatterplot will provide useful indicators concerning how to analyze the relationship.  When many of the correlations are near $\pm 1,$ it is likely you will benefit from transforming them all.  In fact, consider the Fisher Z transformation as the default way of representing the correlations.